# nuxt.js -> custom routes without axios how to get the 'id'

Tags: nuxt.js

So in my nuxt.js project I need a custom route as described here https://nuxtjs.org/examples/custom-routes

What I have implmented so far is the following.

file: pages\trails.vue

```
...
<nuxt-link v-bind:to="'/trail/' + trail.article_code">{{ trail.article_description }}</nuxt-link>
...
```

This would be equivelent to the index.vue file. If I'm correct no additional code is in this file which is relevant

file: pages\trail\_id

```
<template>
    <div class="vttTrails">
        <div class="ui grid centered">
            <div v-for="(trail, index) in listTrail">
                <div class="ui card">
                    {{ trail.article_code }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import feathers from 'feathers/client';
    import socketio from 'feathers-socketio/client';
    import hooks from 'feathers-hooks';
    import io from 'socket.io-client';
    import * as process from "../../nuxt.config";

    const vttSocket = io(process.env.backendUrl);
    const vttFeathers = feathers()
        .configure(socketio(vttSocket))
        .configure(hooks());

    const serviceArticles = vttFeathers.service('articles');

    export default {
        layout: 'default',
        data: function() {
            return {
                listTrail: [],
                curLanguage: this.$store.state.site.curLanguage,
                curCategory: this.$store.state.site.curCategory
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            return serviceArticles.find({
                query: {
                    category_id: this.$store.state.site.curCategory,
                    article_code: '',
                    $sort: {
                        article_rating: 1
                    },
                    $select: [
                        'id',
                        ['article_description_' + this.$store.state.site.curLanguage, 'article_description'],
                        'article_length',
                        'article_ascend',
                        'article_code',
                        'article_at',
                    ]
                }
            }).then(page => {
                this.listTrail = page.data;
            })
        },
    }
</script>
```

So here I put the entire file, just in case. Clicking a link will go to e.g. "trail\cwu" which is correct, for I have that. The value "cwu" needs to go into `article_code: ''`. I tried to do `mounted: function(params)` but it doesn't work.

**Question**

What do I need to do to get the 'params' part in my '_id.vue'? Eventually I'll tweak the select, for it will only return one ofcourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay. So what I have now done is change the data function in the '_id.vue' file. It now contains:

```
data: function() {
            return {
                listTrail: [],
                curLanguage: this.$store.state.site.curLanguage,
                curCategory: this.$store.state.site.curCategory,
                curTrail:  window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]
            }
        },
```

It may not be the correct method, but it sure works.